# OpenScholar not redirecting correctly

Tags: redirection

I have my Openscholar server inside my network with an internal IP and on my firewall I assigned an external IP to redirect traffic to the internal IP. I can access the index page from outside using the outside IP address but when I go to a user's page (/?q=someusername) it redirects into my internal IP address.

Here is an example:
Main Page: http://65.79.20.22

if you click on one of the user websites it redirects into http://10.1.0.22 and of course its not available from outside.

Any ideas? Thanks advance!